# Search two or more DB columns with Android Search Dialog

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a three column DB where the Android Search dialog is working correctly. But I'd like to be able to type in a work or phrase from two different columns and have it return all results where the searched phrase is either in one or the other column, or both columns. I'm using the below method:

```
    //--- GET RECORDS FOR SEARCH
public Cursor searchDB(String query) {  
return db.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_COLUMN1, KEY_COLUMN2, 
KEY_COLUMN3 }, KEY_COLUMN1 + " LIKE" + "'%" + query + "%' OR " + KEY_COLUMN2 +  
" LIKE" + "'%" + query + "%' OR " + KEY_COLUMN3 + " LIKE" + "'%" + query + "%'",  
null, null, null, null, null);  
}
//--- END Get Records for Search
```

So this works fine if you have a DB like this:

```
    COL1     COL2     COL3
______________________

Hi       there    guys
how      are      you
```

and you searched on "Hi" it would return "Hi there guys". but what I want to do is search on "Hi there" and have it return the whole row of all three columns - "Hi there guys". I tried adding:

```
OR "+ KEY_COLUMN2 + KEY_COLUMN3 + " LIKE" + "'%" + query + "%'"
```

but that crashes the search when a search is run.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should apply one more step before querying the database.

You should split your `query` string in an array of words.

Then a solution would be to use the selectionArgs parameter to pass the words of your query:

```
String[] queryWords = splitInWords(query); // your own method to split a string in words
db.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_COLUMN1, KEY_COLUMN2, KEY_COLUMN3 }, 
KEY_COLUMN1 + " LIKE" + " ? OR " + KEY_COLUMN2 + " LIKE" + " ? OR " + KEY_COLUMN3 + " LIKE" + " ?", queryWords, null, null, null, null);
```

The problem with this previous one is you're supposed to have three words (I have never tried I don't know for sure what result you'll get).
Another solution is to create a selection string:

```
String[] queryWords = splitInWords(query); // your own method to split a string in words
String selection = "";
String[] keyColumns = new String[]{KEY_COLUMN1, KEY_COLUMN2, KEY_COLUMN3};
for (int i = 0; i < queryWords.length; i++){
  if ( i > 1){
  selection += " OR ";
  }
selection += keyColumns[i] + " LIKE " + queryWords[i];
}
```

Well it might not be exactly what you're looking for but you'll adapt depending on what you expect to be queried (you can also build a longer selection string with all the pairs key/queryWord). And I never found any better idea to handle this kind of queries.